# How do I save a section of a pygame screen and blit it to another location?

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

I am making a program with a graph that scrolls and I just need to move a section of the screen.

If I do something like this:

```
import pygame

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((300, 300))

sub = screen.subsurface((0,0,20,20))

screen.blit(sub, (30,40))

pygame.display.update()
```

It gives the error message: pygame.error: Surfaces must not be locked during blit

I assume it means the child is locked to its parent surface or something but how else could I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`screen.subsurface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.subsurface) creates a surface, which reference to the original surface. From documentation:

> Returns a new Surface that shares its pixels with its new parent.

To avoid undefined behaviour, the surfaces get locked. You've to [`.copy`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.copy) the surface, before you can [`.blit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) it to its source:

```py
sub = screen.subsurface((0,0,20,20)).copy()
screen.blit(sub, (30,40))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just don't draw to the screen surface directly. Create a `Surface` for each part of your game/UI, and blit each of those to the screen.

```
import pygame

def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))

    # create two parts: a left part and a right part
    left_screen = pygame.Surface((400, 480))
    left_screen.fill((100, 0, 0))

    right_screen = pygame.Surface((240, 480))
    right_screen.fill((200, 200, 0))

    x = 100
    while True:
        events = pygame.event.get()
        for e in events:
            if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return

        # don't draw to the screen surface directly
        # draw stuff either on the left_screen or right_screen
        x += 1
        left_screen.fill(((x / 10) % 255, 0, 0))

        # then just blit both parts to the screen surface
        screen.blit(left_screen, (0, 0))
        screen.blit(right_screen, (400, 0))

        pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```